# Elements in Javascript object coming out undefined

Tags: javascript, json

To construct an object like this:

```
params (Object) (defaults to: {}) —
    Delete — required — (map)
        Objects — required — (Array<map>)
            Key — required — (String) Key name of the object to delete.
```

I'm doing this:

```
var params = {
    Bucket : data.bucket,
    Delete: [{
    Objects:[{ Key:""}] }]  
};

for(i=0;i<data.keys.length;i++){
    params.Delete[0].Objects[i].Key = data.keys[i];
}
```

It breaks on the `Key` with

```
params.Delete[0].Objects[i].Key = data.keys[i];
                                ^
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'Key' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

---

It turns out there is only one `Key` inside of `Objects`. I'd like to put as many keys as I want inside of `Objects` so as to properly construct the object. How can I do this?

Comment: because Objects[1] is undefined...

Comment: Even if the rightside value of assignment is wrong, you would get the same error. Javascript fails the complete line and complains about leftside value. I thought the statement must be  `params.Delete[0].Objects[i].Key = data[i];`. Because you are looping through `data.keys.length` which was not known to us, We can not judge the number of looping iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many object literals are in the `Objects` array?  From your initialization it only looks like 1.  But you are using a for loop, implying you expect more than one.

That error means `Objects[i]` is undefined for whatever value of `i` you reach when it occurs.

It seems like you need to do something like

```
 for(i=0;i<data.keys.length;i++){
    params.Delete[0].Objects.push({Key: data.keys[i]})
 }
```

to get new object literals into your `Objects` array as you process your data (change your definition of `params` to just have an empty array for `Objects` initially).

Comment: I want there to be as many `Keys` as there are in `data.keys`. I thought that the array of `Objects` would be dynamic

Comment: *"How many object literals with a Key property are in the Objects array?"* Or indeed, without a `Key` property...

Comment: @Houseman: It is, but when `i` is `1`, `Objects[i]` is `undefined`. You're trying to treat it like an object. You probably meant `.Objects[i] = { Key: data.keys[i] };`

Answer (score 0):

Your `params.Delete[0].Objects` here has only one object in it and it happens when the `i` is 1. you are counting a for loop based on the other loop with 2 different length.

```
data.keys
```

is different from:

```
params.Delete[0].Objects
```

this one has only one object, whereas the first one has more than one object.